# Cant run gTTS in Django

Tags: python, django, deployment, backend

I am trying to build **text to voice** **app** and I had a **problem** with **gTTS.**

the code I try

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from gtts import gTTS
from  django import  forms

textfortts = []

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
        tts = forms.CharField(label= " convert text to audio here")

def text_to_voice(request):
    if request.method == "POST"     :
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         tts = form.cleaned_data["tts"]
         textfortts.append(tts)
    obj = say(language='en-us', text= textfortts)
    return render(request, "text_to_voice_main.html",{
        "form": UploadFileForm(),
        "lang": "en-us",
        "text": "text to say",
    })
```

**text_to_voice_main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text to voice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <audio
         src="{% say lang text %}"
         controls
         {% load gTTS %}
        ></audio>
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

I **need** to have a **text to voice converter**. can i know what is the **probelms** and **how** i can **fix** it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.